# Error: constant string too long

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

```
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.setText("massive wall of text goes here")
```

This gives an error: constant string too long. Any ways to fix this? I could divide the wall of text and have more than one edittexts but this could mess up with my code. Any ways besides this? Thanks a lot

Comment: you could try to divide text in multi line in the code... but why you need a so long text? can't you put this text in another place?

Comment: can you show your xml. All i want to see is that your layout_width is wrap_content.

Comment: <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:gravity="top|left" />

Comment: Might want to try using a StringBuffer instead. I don't think that your error is with the Android EditText as such, but more with the Java String class.

Comment: a string literal can only be 64k long.

Comment: you text should go in an xml files in the `res/values` directory under a `string` item.

Comment: this actually gave "cannot resolve symbol R" and had to rebuild my project completely >_>